# Preload WooCommerce star.woff Font

Tags: wordpress, optimization, woocommerce

Google's PageSpeed Insights is telling me that WooCommerce star.woff font is making my site load slower and suggests me to use `<link rel=preload>` tag to save an estimated of 1.95s. Can someone please show me how can I apply this tag to a WooCommerce font without messing around with the plug-in's files?

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of days I've found a solution. I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it worked for me, so I'll leave it here in case it helps somebody.

Add the following hook to your functions.php to enqueue the font and WordPress will add the link to the header with the `<link rel=preload>` tag.

```
// Enqueue Your Font
function my_queue_items() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'rating-stars', '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/star.woff', array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_queue_items', 99 );

// Add Crossorigin Attribute To Your Font
function style_attributes( $html, $handle ) {
if ( 'rating-stars' === $handle ) {
return str_replace( "media='all'", "media='all' crossorigin='anonymous'", $html );
}
return $html;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'style_attributes', 10, 2 );
```

This saved me 1s load speed.

Answer (score 2):

The better solution is just to add the following line into [your-theme]/header.php

```
<link rel="preload" href="Font URL Showing in PageSpeed" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">
```